# where is Enum.values() defined?

Tags: java, enums

Every Java enumeration has a static values() method can be used like this

```
for (MyEnum enum : MyEnum.values()) {
    // Do something with enum
}
```

However, I cannot figure out where this method is defined. There's no mention of it in the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) and it doesn't appear anywhere in the source file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is required by the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9): `values` and `valueOf` will be implicitly declared for all Enums:

```
/**
* Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be
* used to iterate over the constants as follows:
*
*    for(E c : E.values())
*        System.out.println(c);
*
* @return an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared
*/
public static E[] values();

/**
* Returns the enum constant of this type with the specified
* name.
* The string must match exactly an identifier used to declare
* an enum constant in this type.  (Extraneous whitespace 
* characters are not permitted.)
* 
* @return the enum constant with the specified name
* @throws IllegalArgumentException if this enum type has no
* constant with the specified name
*/
public static E valueOf(String name);
```

These methods are added during compile time, so if you use `javap` to disassemble the code, you can actually look at their body.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious on why the enum is designed like this? AFAIK, the most of the definition was inside the class in Java

Comment: Does this mean that writing the bytecode could let you do hideous things like excluding a legacy enum value?

Answer (score 4):

It's defined in the [JLS, section 8.9.3 "Enum Members"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3)

Comment: In the spirit of SO, I believe dropping a link to a giant pile of manuals is not terribly kind or helpful.

Comment: @Chrips: When the answer was posted, the link linked to a specific section of the Java Language Specification specifying the members of enums. The link no longer works. I will try to update it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not explicitly defined, just like `length` property of java array is not defined. It is implicitly available for concrete Enum type.